Connection is closed by foreign host
How to solve problem if the "Connection is closed by foreign host" during receiver mail provided

Here, the picture shows that the connection was closed by foreign host.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213364/telnet-connection-closed-by-foreign-host

please remove the picture and post the text instead

This Unix & Linux question asked the exact same thing, just not specifically for a mail service.
As this answer explains:

The most likely cause is that someone is using the port, and the application running only accepts one connection at a time, and refuses any additional connections.

If the receiver port is already in use, close that connection (if you can,) and hopefully it'll then work.

The other possibility is that the destination end is actively dropping the connection.
For instance if the destination server has security in place, and having received the sender and recipient details decides that it doesn't handle email to/from that domain, then it may simply drop the connection. That's especially possible where you have some kind of proxy firewall in front of the actual mail server. The mail server itself may normally reply saying that the address isn't known (or some other error) if the request reaches it, but the proxy may drop the request before it even reaches the mail server.
